# Migration from Cognos cubes to SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cognos

I have a requirement of migrating Cognos cubes to SSAS.
Can some body guide me Is it possible to access Cognos cubes by SSAS?

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, the PowerCube itself must have been generated from a database of some kind (or flat files), so you will just need to import the source data and redo the model in SSAS.

Comment: So the answer is Yes its possible ? could you link me some sample websites or tutorial of how this is done? thanks!

Comment: and i dont want to do it from scratch.. is it possible to access the ready made cognos cube? by ssas ?

Comment: I've never seen any options to import a Cognos cube's definition (.mdl or .pyj) into SSAS.  It is likely not going to work that way so it would need to be redone from scratch.

Comment: do you have any further information so that i convince my boss,like its not possible and we need more resources to be done from scratch.!

Comment: You're importing to SSAS, so it's really down to what formats SSAS supports for import of metadata.

Comment: +1.. @chsh..could you please elaborate i'm finding difficult to catch the answer here.