# Getting started with migrating the cognos cubes to ssas

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cognos, cognos-8

I have this requirement of migrating the existing `cognos cubes` to `ssas cubes`,
can somebody guide me from where do i get started ?

And is it possible to use existing `cognos cubes` somehow in `ssas`?
or is it possible to import the existing `cognos cubes` to `ssas`?

I am very new to both the technologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migration from Cognos cubes to SSAS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894502/migration-from-cognos-cubes-to-ssas)

Comment: @chsh : that doesn't answer either.. the question is how do i get started with migration part..what compnents are there having similar functionality ? thanks!

Comment: There isn't (as far as I've seen) a mechanism for SSAS to import the metadata file from Cognos (.pyj or .mdl) so you would need to redo the model from scratch in SSAS.  I flagged as possible duplicate because another user asked the same question only a couple of days ago.

Comment: SSAS technology is very advanced compared to Cognos cubes. I believe you should not try to migrate but completely redesign them. Otherwise you will miss lots of features provided. Depending on the complexity of your cubes, that would mean hiring a consultant. Since learning SSAS at an advanced level takes minimum 6 months for a person with Essbase/Cognos experience.